# Blob Row too big too fit in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

How can I limit the size of the image when saving to SQLite? I have this error when I retrieve which I think didn't get the big size of the blob Image from SQLite. However, I tried putting limit 500 in the query like this `SELECT id,cash_card,hh_number,cc_image FROM CgList limit 500`, but the result is the same, it crashes my application.

In short, Is there any way to reduce the file size of the image when inserting to the SQLite database?

*Error*

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException: Row too big to fit
> into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=4

*Insert data and blob*

```
 public void insertData(String cash_card, String hh_number,String series_number ,byte[] cc_image,byte[] id_image){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO CgList VALUES (NULL,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.bindString(1, cash_card);
    statement.bindString(2, hh_number);
    statement.bindString(3, series_number);
    statement.bindBlob(4, cc_image);
    statement.bindBlob(5, id_image);
    statement.executeInsert();
}
```

*Getting data*

```
  Cursor cursor = ScannedDetails.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,cash_card,hh_number,cc_image FROM CgList");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {   // the error is here
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

        list.add(new Inventory(name, price, image, id));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

*When I click button to save to SQLite*

```
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                    edtCashCard.getText().toString().trim(),
                    edtHhnumber.getText().toString().trim(),
                    edtSeriesno.getText().toString().trim(),
                    imageViewToByte(mPreviewCashcard),
                    imageViewToByte(mPreview4PsId)
            );
        }
    });
```

*Converting Image To Byte*

```
 public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
   Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
   ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
   byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
   return byteArray;
 }
```

*Updated*

I think this is the problem when capturing an image it provide bigger size, I need this because after I capture the image I want to crop the image for some purpose but I want to display the actual capture not the cropped image to another activity

```
 private void pickCamera() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "NewPic");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image to Text");
    image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
}
```

> OnActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLER_CODE){
            CropImage.activity(data.getData()).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(this);
        }
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){

            CropImage.activity(image_uri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(this);
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if(resultCode ==RESULT_OK){
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            resultUri.getPath();
            mPreviewIv.setImageURI(resultUri);
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)mPreviewIv.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            TextRecognizer recognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

            if(!recognizer.isOperational()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                SparseArray<TextBlock> items = recognizer.detect(frame);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i<items.size(); i++){
                    TextBlock myItem = items.valueAt(i);
                    sb.append(myItem.getValue());
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
                
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScannedDetails.class);   
                //camera
                i.putExtra("CashCardImage",image_uri.toString());  //This data pass to another activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Retrieve to another Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   String resultUri = extras.getString("CashCardImage");
   Uri myUri = Uri.parse(resultUri);
   mPreviewCashCard.setImageURI(myUri);
```

The other one I tried when saving to SQLITE the size is not big it's just KIB, I think the problem is on the 1st PickCamera but those code need for cropping an Image

```
 private void pickCamera() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(ScannedDetails.this, InventoryList.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLiteBlobTooBigException: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959944/sqliteblobtoobigexception-row-too-big-to-fit-into-cursorwindow-requiredpos-0-t)

Comment: btw. keeping such big blob in sqlite is highly unefficient (saving/fetching)

Comment: @ArthurAttout  thanks for your response but I didn't get the idea of the answer there can you tell me what's going on, it is the problem when inserting data?

Comment: @snachmsm thanks for your response Is there anyway to limit the size of the image?

Comment: I tried the 1st answer above and it display the image but the question is , is there anyway how can I limit the size of the image when saving into the SQLITE?  @Arthur Attout

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your response I added the code above on how I managed the Image, Is there anyway just need help about this one

Comment: That is the wrong code added. We still know nothing. For you function insertData() you should show us how you convert your image to `byte[] cc_image,byte[]id_image`. And explain why you use two byte arrays. Also tell size of original image file and length of arrays. Start with the obtained uri.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your response, I updates the code above on how I convert Image to Byte

Comment: @blackapps this is the source I've been following  [link](https://github.com/quocvn/food-sqlite-demo) Do you have recommendations for this problem? I'm just out of option how can I managed to lessen the file size though it displays and insert in SQLite Android studio but It is not best practice to insert huge file in SQLite

Comment: Sorry but what should i do with that link? Looking at a video? No way. Post your code. And adapt the title. Also remove that android-studio tag.

Comment: @blackapps Should I make a new post or change the title of my post?

Comment: @blackapps Sorry I didn't get adapt the title

Comment: ??? you can just edit it. I dont understand.

Comment: `imageViewToByte(ImageView image)` Why do you first put your file in an ImageView? I would expect a function `UriToByte(Uri uri)`. You can have a good reason but i wonder. Further you should try both functions and compare sizes. You also did not tell us the sizes i requested.

Comment: `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` Is the original image a .png? Why do you compress to .png where compressing to .jpg or .webp would give much less bytes?

Answer (score 1):

> However, I tried putting limit 500 in the query like this SELECT id,cash_card,hh_number,cc_image FROM CgList limit 500

LIMIT limits the number of rows returned, is does not limit the size of a row.

The issue is that a single row exceeds the capacity of the cache/buffer (CursorWindow) that a Cursor uses. This restriction does not apply when inserting the said row/rows.

The typical solution is to not store images but to instead store a reference, such as a file path, from which the image (or other large item) can then be retrieved.

[Here's an example that stores images less than a set size (100k in the example) as a blob and those larger as files in data/data/myimages, which could be another solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633055/guide-to-use-a-large-sqlite-propulated-database/51633408#51633408)

It is possible to break a large image into chunks of data and store/retrieve that. [Here's an example of doing that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321154/how-to-use-images-in-android-sqlite-that-are-larger-than-the-limitations-of-a-cu/55321155#55321155)

Comment: Thanks for your response I tried but I still don't get the idea, I'm also a slow learner, I don't know how can I apply that source to my code, please need help

Comment: @ShainnahJane Your first step is to decide how you are going handle the storage of the images, as 1) chunks of data, as 2) a reference to files or 3) a mix of storing those that can be stored and others as references. Then examine the relevant example and extract/modify the methods to suit.

Comment: Thanks for your response I intent to save data with images to SQLite in my phone , the images is comes from my Camera , the question is what is the best way to save image should I use `BLOB` or just the path of the imageUri?

Comment: @ShainnahJane the uri, although this would be susceptible to the image being moved.

Comment: Actually I have two ImagePreview when saving to SQLITE the file size of the two images are different, one is just only  `KIB` and the other one is bigger which is `MiB`  I think there's no problem inserting in SQLite the difference is that how I capture the camera, but I don't know why they have different file size

Comment: I added code above with some explanation can you help me? I'm confused what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't store an image directly in your database. Instead, save the image to a file or to a webserver. Then in the database store the file path or URL to the image.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I intent to save data to SQLite in my phone then I want to sync all data with images and send it through API, but for now, I know it's a bit common to ask but still don't have yet solve my problem on how can I limit the image size to my SQLite can you help pls.