# How to increase CursorWindow Size, Expo-SQLite?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo-sqlite

**Expo-SQL**

```js
const printSearchTable = () => {
  db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql(
      "select * from 'Literature'",
      [],
      (tx, res) =>
        console.log(
          "Succeeded to get Contents From Table 'Literature'--->",
          res
        ),
      (tx, err) =>
        console.log("Failed to get Contents From Table 'Literature'", err)
    );
  });
};
```

When I do the above I get this error.

`Failed to get Contents From Table 'Literature' Error: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=2`

What can I do to make this work? The data type for both rows is `text`. This is the statement I used to  create the table.

`create table 'Literature'(abbr text primary key, value text)`

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959944/sqliteblobtoobigexception-row-too-big-to-fit-into-cursorwindow-requiredpos-0-t